# Please assist me in using python

Tags: python

I am just starting out in college learning python. I understand my question is very simple but I would love some help on it.

Write a program that asks the user to enter a word (a String) and prints “Long” if the length of the word is greater than 10, “Ok if the length of the word is exactly 10, and “Short” if the length of the word is less than 10.

I will post my program below. It is spitting out this error "TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'

My code:

```
x = len(input ("Enter a Word"))
if len >10:
    print("Long")
elif len ==10:
    print("OK")
elif len <10:
    print("Short")
```

Comment: You want `if x > 10`. `len` is a builtin function

Comment: `len` is a function. The result of your call to `len` is given to `x`. So your code should be: `if x > 10:`.

Answer (score 3):

Your code should be:

```
    x = len(input ("Enter a Word"))
    if x >10:
        print("Long")
    elif x ==10:
        print("OK")
    elif x <10:
        print("Short")
```

You are already storing the length of the string in x, so you need to compare with x and not len. Also, len is an inbuilt function.

Comment: You might want to replace `elif x < 10:` with `else:`.